# Problems with android TabHost

Tags: android, android-layout

I am doing an app, and on this one I want to use tabs.

This is the Activity where I manage my tabs:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    Resources res = getResources();
    tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, WUL4Bus.class);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("mapa");
    spec.setIndicator("Mapa",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_mapa));
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Esquematico.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("esquemático");
    spec.setIndicator("Esquemático",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_listado));
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ListaTickets.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tickets");
    spec.setIndicator("Tickets",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_bono));
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ListaFavoritos.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("favoritos");
    spec.setIndicator("Favoritos",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_directo));
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, About.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("acerca de");
    spec.setIndicator("Acerca de",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_info));
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    instancia = this;
}
```

This is the layout :

> 

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My first problem is that, when I run the app, it is properly working, but it doesn´t show the icons. Without the HorizontalScrollView there was no problems, but now, it is not showing the icons.

The other problem is that I would like my app to show only one tab per screen(just like Google Play does) and not several tabs.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

we add like this every time we add only same value just change like this

```
intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, Esquematico.class);
spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("esquemático");
spec.setIndicator("Esquemático",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_listado));
spec.setContent(intent1);
tabHost.addTab(spec1);

intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this, ListaTickets.class);
spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tickets");
spec.setIndicator("Tickets",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_bono));
spec.setContent(intent2);
tabHost.addTab(spec2);

intent3 = new Intent().setClass(this, ListaFavoritos.class);
spec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("favoritos");
spec.setIndicator("Favoritos",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_directo));
spec.setContent(intent3);
tabHost.addTab(spec3);........
 ...............................................
```

see [THIS](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/) example....